# swift protocol conformance with duplicate function names

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

```
class A {
    func test(string: String, another defaultValue: String = "") {
        ///...
    }
}

class B {
    func test(string: String, different defaultValue: Bool = true) {
        ///...
    }
}

protocol Test {
    func test(string: String)
}

extension A: Test {
    func test(string: String) {
        self.test(string: string)
    }
}

extension B: Test {
    func test(string: String) {
        self.test(string: string)
    }
}
```

When I do this I get the following error

> Function call causes an infinite recursion

How to confirm to the protocol `Test` to the classes which have similar function names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When A or B conform to Test, there is no way for the program to know which `.test` you're calling, cause the internal `.test` methods in A & B have default values.

To resolve the ambiguity, you can be specific:

```
extension A: Test {
    func test(string: String) {
      self.test(string: string, another: "")
    }
}

extension B: Test {
    func test(string: String) {
      self.test(string: string, different: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call class methods with full signature:

```
extension A: Test {
    func test(string: String) {
        self.test(string: string, another: "")
    }
}

extension B: Test {
    func test(string: String) {
        self.test(string: string, different: true)
    }
}
```

As swift allows method overloading, you may use the same function name with different signatures.
In your example class methods have different signatures, comparing to the protocol methods, so it is fine. However class methods have default values and can be called without full signature and in this case it is ambiguous as the signature become the same.

Comment: OP wants to call the protocol method and not the class method

Comment: Hi @Alex! This answer looks fine for the question, but similar to the other answer I would have liked a small explanation why the code needs to be changed in the way you suggested. Similar to the other answer.

Comment: @Garuno 
I have added more details to my answer